# Search for word and italicize

Tags: formatting, italic

I'm using LaTeX to format my books now. When I transitioned one of my books from Word to LaTeX, the italicized words didn't carry over, so I used the command `\textit{word}`. But after sending it to my editor, I see that one group of words needs to be italicized every time.

I need to make the words "South Park" italicized in the entire document. I found one suggestion that I could put in the preamble:

```
\newcommand*{\southpark}{\textit{South Park}}
```

But this wasn't quite what I was looking for. I'm looking for a command that can search my document for "South Park" and italicize every instance of it. Is this possible?

Comment: If you wrap text in backticks `like so` it is displayed as inline code. If you indent it with four spaces it comes out as displayed code.

Comment: What LaTeX editor are you using? Most editors nowadays have the search-and-replace function. Just search all instances of `South Park` in your `.tex` file and replace them with `\textit{South Park}` using the editor

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. I didn't even think about that. I'll give it a try right now.

Comment: I was about to answer the same thing as @Kevin C.

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly what you want, but very close, I hope. You can use your editor to change every occurence of the word South (with the word Park after it) into `\South` (backslash added). Then the definition as in the following example does the rest.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\South Park{\textit{South Park}}

\begin{document}

This is \South Park, this is \South Park, this is \South Park, this is \South Park, this is \South Park, but beware: this is also \South 
Park.

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Limitations:* The word `Park` must appear after `\South`. Otherwise TeX will stop with an error message.

Comment: why not just change `South Park` what's the advantage of only searching for half the string and then using a delimited argument?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Because OP wants TeX to do it. I know: it is probably too early to introduce definition with a structure, but OP seems to be a TeX enthusiast.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure of what exacly you are looking for, but I suggest that you use the replace function of your LaTeX editor (assuming that it has it).

[image]